# Google cloud functions inside VPC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is it not possible to run GCP cloud functions (or any GCP serverless compute resources for that matter) inside private networks? Are they always using shared capacity and public networks? Am I missing something? Don't confuse this with egress, I know it is possible to access private networks from serverless resources, but is it possible to limit access to the functions at the network level? AFAIK you can do this with lambdas on AWS and with app service on Azure (although on Azure it was expensive since you need to move away from shared capacity).

Comment: There's a whole section in the docs about this? https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc And then for ingress "Allow internal traffic only"

Comment: @Hitobat The link you posted is about traffic from functions into your VPC, exactly what I mentioned I wasn't interested in. I don't see anything about running serverless compute resources inside your VPC networks?

Comment: You can limit access to your functions for network traffic only from your VPC. If that's not what you're asking then I'm having trouble understanding the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 way traffic in Cloud Function: ingress and egress

- Ingress: [you can limit the traffic coming from internet, or uniquely from project VPC or VPC SC](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#ingress_settings)
- Egress: By default, the traffic is directly routed to internet. [You can use a serverless VPC connector for](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#egress_settings):

  - Either routing only the private IP (RFC1918) to the VPC
  - Or routing all the traffic to the VPC.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @VilleRinne can you please explain it to me?. Im trying the same thing but with Cloud Run.

Comment: @AlejandroBarone, Cloud Run ingress feature is coming (today in private alpha, I tested it). Stay tune.